# Anchoring imageViews to the Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]

In this image they have implemented a Collapsing Toolbar with a parallax ImageView and a FAB anchored to the Toolbar. In the app I'm making, I need to anchor an ImageView instead of a Floating Action Button while still keeping all the fade out and in animations. How do I do this?

My current

> activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="252dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/random"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.example.sudarshan.testapp.MLRoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="152dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    android:id="@+id/circularImage"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The ImageView gets anchored but it does not disappear and reappear like the FAB does.

Answer (score 5):

You could construct a custom behaviour class that extends `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`, then attach it to your `ImageView` by adding the `app:layout_behavior="com.path.to.behavior.class"` attribute.

Alternatively, add an `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` to the `Activity` where you declare your **FAB** and `AppBarLayout`, and use the `verticalOffset` parameter to determine when to start an `AlphaAnimation` on your `ImageView`.

**Edit**

```
public static MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    private static final float THRESHOLD_PERCENTAGE = 0.2F;

    private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //...
      mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
      mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {

        int maxScroll = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        float progressPercentage = (float) (Math.abs(offset)/maxScroll);

        if (progressPercentage >= THRESHOLD_PERCENTAGE) {
            //start an alpha animation on your ImageView here (i.e. fade out)
        } else {
            //Add an opposite animation here (i.e. it fades back in again)
        }
    }
```

Adjusting the `THRESHOLD_PERCENTAGE` value will alter the point at which the animation `ImageView` begins.

Comment: @SudarshanSunder I've added an example of how you can use `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener`